# How to take shortcode and content separately from a page?

Tags: filters, shortcode

I have a page with content and shortcode for the contact form.
I want to display the content of the page in one div and the shortcode in another div(that means the form should render in another div). How to implement this?
I tried
`<?php 
  remove_filter( 'the_content', 'do_shortcode', 11 );
  the_content();
  add_filter( 'the_content', 'do_shortcode', 11 );*/
 ?>`

for filtering the content only...but it displays the shortcode as it is.([contact-form-7 id="72" title="Contact form 1" html_class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-12 dose-contact-form row"]).How to ffx this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I used the following  codes and it worked for me . To remove the shortcode from the content, I Used this 
`<?php
$content = get_the_content();
$content = preg_replace("/\[.*]/m", " ", $content);

$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $content);
echo $content;
?>`

and the following code to get the shortcode only from post content

`<?php
$pattern = get_shortcode_regex();
$matches = array();
preg_match_all("/$pattern/s", get_the_content(), $matches);

echo preg_replace_callback( "/$pattern/s", 'do_shortcode_tag',           $matches[0][0] );
?>`